# Optimizing Uniform Distribution of Attributes in Item Selection: A Combinatorial Problem

Tags: combinatorics, algorithms

I am an engineer with limited mathematical proficiency, and I have encountered a quite challenging mathematical problem during my work. The problem as a whole is intricate, but I will try my best to provide a simplified version of it first.

I have 10 items to choose from, each of which has two attributes.

Attribute A has three states, and attribute B also has three states.

These states are represented as 0, 1, and 2. Therefore, the sample space for each item is { $(a, b)$ | $0\leq a \leq 2$, $0 \leq b \leq 2$ }.

The next step is to find a way to select 6 out of the 10 items such that both A state and B state distributions of the picked items are uniform. Here are the further details:

(1) For the uniform distribution of the A state, let's denote

$a_0$ = count of '0' in the first dimension of picks,

$a_1$ = count of '1' in the first dimension of picks,

$a_2$ = count of '2' in the first dimension of picks.

I define the "unevenness function" for A state as
$u_A = (a_0 - \frac{6}{3})^2 + (a_1 - \frac{6}{3})^2 + (a_2 - \frac{6}{3})^2$.

This definition mimics the standard deviation, aiming for each state count to approach the expected value in a "perfectly uniform state", which equals the total picks divided by the number of states. Hence, a smaller $u_A$ indicates a more uniform distribution for the A state.

(2) For the uniform distribution of the B state, we can similarly denote

$b_0$ = count of '0' in the second dimension of picks,

$b_1$ = count of '1' in the second dimension of picks,

$b_2$ = count of '2' in the second dimension of picks.

I define the "unevenness function" for B state as
$u_B = (b_0 - \frac{6}{3})^2 + (b_1 - \frac{6}{3})^2 + (b_2 - \frac{6}{3})^2$.

(3) The total unevenness function, denoted as $u$, is defined as $u = u_A + u_B$. The ultimate goal is to minimize $u$ to achieve the most uniform state.

---

Here's an example. Let's say the 10 items are as follows:

\begin{align*}
\text{Item1} &= (0, 1) \\
\text{Item2} &= (0, 0) \\
\text{Item3} &= (0, 1) \\
\text{Item4} &= (1, 2) \\
\text{Item5} &= (1, 0) \\
\text{Item6} &= (1, 0) \\
\text{Item7} &= (1, 2) \\
\text{Item8} &= (2, 1) \\
\text{Item9} &= (2, 2) \\
\text{Item10} &= (2, 1) \\
\end{align*}

Assuming that I arbitrarily choose the first six items, then:
$u_A = (a_0 - \frac{6}{3})^2 + (a_1 - \frac{6}{3})^2 + (a_2 - \frac{6}{3})^2  = (3 - 2)^2 + (3 - 2)^2 + (0 - 2)^2 = 2$,
$u_B = (b_0 - \frac{6}{3})^2 + (b_1 - \frac{6}{3})^2 + (b_2 - \frac{6}{3})^2 = (3 - 2)^2 + (2 - 2)^2 + (1 - 2)^2 = 2$.

Therefore, the total unevenness for this picks set is $u = u_A + u_B = 4$.

On the other hand, when I make a "wiser" selection of items "1, 2, 5, 7, 8, 9", $u = u_A + u_B = 0$ because this choice ensures a very uniform distribution for both the A and B states, with each state appearing exactly twice.

My question is, is it possible to find the optimal "picks", i.e., the minimum value of $u$, without resorting to brute force?

---

Here is the complete version of the problem I am facing: Given $n$ items, each with $\alpha$ A states and $\beta$ B states, find the best $m$ items out of the $n$ to minimize $u = u_A + u_B = \left((a_0 - \frac{m}{\alpha})^2 + (a_1 - \frac{m}{\alpha})^2 + \dots + (a_\alpha - \frac{m}{\alpha})^2\right) + \left((b_0 - \frac{m}{\beta})^2 + (b_1 - \frac{m}{\beta})^2 + \dots + (b_\beta - \frac{m}{\beta})^2\right)$, and provide the selection method.

P.S. In practical situations, $n$ might be very small (might be less than 50)or exceed a thousand while $m$ is roughly 10, in most case making exhaustive enumeration almost impossible.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From a quick look it is a quadratic programming problem. To my knowledge there is no efficient (i.e. polynomial) algorithm to solve it optimally when variables are integer.

Integer variables means the object are either picked or not so they are in $\{0,1\}$, while there exists polynomial algorithm when the vars are in $[0,1]$.

However as it is a classical problem in practice I have no doubt you will find numerous good heuristic, although maybe not optimal.

Comment: Thrilled to see your response!!! This spares me from digging deeper and agonizing over this issue. I greatly appreciate your feedback.